# multiple User.IsInRole on same page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i faced this problem

when i multiple this condition on different position on same page i'v got error

```
@if(User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = category.id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = category.id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = category.id })
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your intent I would use for example (my understanding is that you want to render a list of actions with a | character between each action) :

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = category.id }) |

text is a Razor syntax to force switching back to the HTML context.